# Formatting Interpolated String or Number in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using d3 to animate text to show a user's progress towards completing a task.  For example, if they've completed 32.51% of the task, the text will animate from 0% to 32.51% over 2 seconds or so.

To do this, I'm using d3's attrTween method on an svg text element in conjunction with d3.interpolate. The interpolation is working great, but I'm having a little trouble formatting the text.  I'd like the text to always display 4 digits, so 0% = 00.00%, 4.31% = 04.31% etc.  It would be nice to be able to do this without necessarily having to post process what the interpolator returns.  In other words, without having to take the returned percentage and check to see if there are 4 digits and add zero padding on either side before placing it in the DOM.

As a test, I tried specifying the format that I would like by setting the a and b values to the interpolator like so `d3.interpolate("00.00", "30.00")`, but the final text is "30" with the trailing zeros cut off.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a custom interpolator to `d3.interpolators` - see [the docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-d3_interpolators). The example given in the docs is very close to yours - the only real change is specifying the output format, which in your case should be:

```
d3.format('05.2f'); // 0-padding, string width 5, 2 decimal places
```

Plugging this into the doc example (note that I also changed the regex appropriately and added the percentage sign):

```
d3.interpolators.push(function(a, b) {
  var re = /^(\d\d\.\d\d)%$/, ma, mb, f = d3.format('05.2f');
  if ((ma = re.exec(a)) && (mb = re.exec(b))) {
    a = parseFloat(ma[1]);
    b = parseFloat(mb[1]) - a;
    return function(t) {
      return f(a + b * t) + '%';
    };
  }
});

d3.interpolate("00.00%", "30.00%")(1/5); // "06.00%"
d3.interpolate("00.00%", "30.00%")(1/3); // "10.00%"
```

Comment: wow thanks so much!  worked like a charm and +1 for referencing the docs and making me aware of pushing a formatter into d3.interpolators